# Задача по информатике с массивами

Tags: python, информатика

```
    import random
x=2000
a=[random.randint (0, 1000) for i in range (0, 70)]
i = 0
for i in range (0, 70):
    i=+1
    if (a[i]+a[i+1])%2==0:
        if (a[i]+a[i+1])<x:
            a[i]+a[i+1]=x
            print (x)
```

Задача заключается в том, что в массива из случайных чисел нужно найти наименьшую сумму двух соседей, которые при этом будут одинаковой четности ( оба четные или нечетные ) На строке с присвоением иксу нового значения (суммы двух а-итых) выдает ошибку "can't assign to operator"

Comment: a[i]+a[i+1]=x это присвоение икса, а не иксу

Comment: точно, спасибо, буквально секунду назад нашел решение, спасибо:)

Answer (score 0):

Строку с основной ошибкой Вам уже указали в комментариях — `x = a[i] + a[i+1]`.
Но после её исправления, код работать всё ещё не будет.

У Вас также есть следующие ошибки:

1. **Определение `x`**

   ```py
   x = 2000
   ```

   Почему именно `2000`?

   Одним из возможных решений будет определить `x` бесконечно большим числом:

   ```py
   x = float('inf')
   ```
2. **Вывод результата**

   ```py
   if ...:
       print(x)
   ```

   Он не должен быть в блоке `if` (как и в блоке `for`). Условие может выполниться несколько раз из-за чего будет многократный вывод.
3. **Кривой счётчик**

   ```py
   i = 0
   for i in range(70):
       i = +1  # i = 1
   ```

   При использовании цикла `for`, Вам не нужно вручную инкрементировать счётчик (хотя вы этого и не делаете, Вы его полностью переопределяете на каждой итерации в `1`).
4. **Выход за пределы списка**

   ```py
   a = [... for i in range(70)]
   for i in range(70):
       a[i+1]  # IndexError: list index out of range
   ```

   Вам необходимо генерировать последовательность на 1 меньше.

---

Учитывая то, что я описал выше, новые возможности `Python 3.8`, стандарт `PEP 8` и собственные предпочтения в оформлении кода, я бы реализовал это так:

```py
import random


def main():
    n = 10
    li = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(n)]

    min_sum = float('inf')
    for i in range(n - 1):
        if (tmp := li[i] + li[i+1]) % 2 == 0 and tmp < min_sum:
            min_sum = tmp

    print(min_sum)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```